# Groovy read and export docx file

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to implement language translator service where I would upload a docx file and parse the content at server side and put back translated content back to their original position. Also, I want to retain the content format. I have tried Apache POI. But I am not able to track the content location and its original format to put back data. Can anyone help?

Comment: Translate the text run-by-run, and replace the text on each individual run rather than by paragraph? (In the Word file formats, everything within one run has the same formatting applied)

Comment: @Gagravarr "translate the text run-by-run": Not a good idea. The ways how Word creates text runs are mysterious sometimes. Maybe each word will be in it's own run even if not formatted different. And translating word by word is not purposefull, is it? But this leads to the conclusion that "put back translated content back to their original position ... retain the content format" is nearly impossible having the chaotic Word format for storing text in text runs.

Comment: @AxelRichter If you take the example paragraph "Word *can* be **quite** fun with how it writes out text", if you didn't do it at least somewhat run based, how would you know which word(s) in the translation should be bold and which italic? Admittedly there's also the issue of where the translation changes the order of the words in the target language and certain words are in other formats...

Comment: @Gagravarr: Correct. That's why I said it is nearly impossible. Some kind  of AI maybe able translating sentences adequate. But translating of emphasizing is at much higher level of AI. So translating the marking of emphasizing by formatting in written text is at this same high level.

Comment: @Gagravarr:  Your example "Word *can* be **quite** fun with how it writes out text." would be "Word *können* sein **ganz** Spaß mit wie es schreibt aus Text." translated to German word(run) by word(run). No German would understand what that means.